# Can required WCF4 DataMemeber's be organized into required groups?

Tags: c#-4.0, wcf

Is there a way to have required DataMember's within a DataContract to be organized into groups so that you really only require group one or group two but no both to be provided?

I am looking to see if there is functionality similar to Workflow Activity validation where you can flag InArgument's with a RequiredArgument and then use OverloadGroup attribute to put these into groups so that only the arguments in one of the specified groups are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible out of the box with `DataContractSerializer` but you can switch to `XmlSerializer` and use [xsd:choice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa6z5baz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) (`XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute`) but be aware that this will affect your data class beacuse this construct has its own requirements.

Comment: Yeah I figured out it was not possible using DataContract.  However thanks for providing an alternative to explore that sounds like it may provide the functionality.  I will look into this.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there is no way to do this. Only way to group is to have two different classes and extract away members/properties into those classes, but still...you won't be able to dictate an "either-on" setting.